# Selenium Java: Unable to Locate Element inside #document section

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Did anyone experience handling the element which is inside the #document section?
I had tried for absolute xpath, JavascriptExecutor, shadow, switchTo but still not able to locate the element.
the html structure as shown in the pic

[html typing version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jm7iT.png)

[image]

Comment: Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why [a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code/HTML and properly format it instead.

Comment: i understand if able to provide the url or paste entire html is good, but this website is from intranet, not able to access from public network.

Comment: That's fine... you can still copy/paste the HTML as text and paste it into your question properly formatted. You also need to provide your current code and any error messages.

Comment: JeffC,let me explain another way, this url is only accessible from a private network with the restricted pc, and this pc is "not allow" to connect internet. Mean that I will never able to copy the "HTML as text" from that machine/that website and paste it here. Is alright, i manually type out the html code u may have a look.

Comment: The OBJECT tag is acting like an IFRAME. Try switching to the OBJECT tag and then accessing the INPUT. You still need to post your code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to locate the element by using `switchTo` method

```
driver.switchTo.frame(driver.findElement(By.tagName("object")));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='custId']")).sendKeys("customer123");
```